# Spring Integration Annotations and the SmartLifecycle interface

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

I have some legacy code I need to port into a spring integration based application. I decided to configure inbound channel adapters via the `@InboundChannelAdapter` annotation, which works as expected.

The problem is I have some code I need to execute when the `start()` and `stop()` methods of the inbound channel adapter are called.

I tried to to this via implementing the `SmartLifecycle` interface, but that didn't get me anywhere. Does anyone have any other suggestions I should try? I'm kinda stuck right now...

Edit: code example

```
@MessageEndpoint
@Component
public class InputSource implements SmartLifecycle {
    public void start() {
        //my code to be executed
    }

    public void stop() {
        //my code
    }

    @InboundChannelAdapter("some.channel")
    public Message<?> read() {
        //my code that returns a message
    }

}
```

The code in `read()` method gets called when I start the inbound channel adapter, but `start()` does not get called when my context is created.

Comment: Can you show some configuration?

Comment: Edited with an example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What version of Spring Integration? This works fine for me with 4.1.0...

```
@EnableIntegration
@MessageEndpoint
@Component
public class InputSource implements SmartLifecycle {

    private boolean running;

    @Override
    public void start() {
        System.out.println("start");
        running = true;
    }

    @Override
    public void stop() {
        running = false;
    }

    @InboundChannelAdapter(value = "toRabbit", poller = @Poller(fixedDelay = "5000", maxMessagesPerPoll = "1"))
    public Message<?> read() {
        return new GenericMessage<String>("foo");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isRunning() {
        return running;
    }

    @Override
    public int getPhase() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAutoStartup() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void stop(Runnable callback) {
        stop();
        callback.run();
    }

}
```

(Even without the `@EnableIntegration` the `start()` method is called).

In any case, bear in mind that the start/stop here are on a different bean (the `InputSource`) whereas the start/stop on the adapter are on its `SourcePollingChannelAdapter`. You can control the order with `phase`.

**EDIT:**

Based on your comments below you want the adapter to start its source. Even if we did that...

```
if (this.source implements Lifecycle) {
    ((Lifecycle) source).start();
}
```

...it wouldn't work here because the source is not your component, it's a `MethodInvokingMessageSource` that knows nothing about the rest of the bean, just the `read()` method.

One work-around would be to subclass `SourcePollingChannelAdapter` and override it's doStart() method...

```
@Override // guarded by super#lifecycleLock
protected void doStart() {
     myInputSource.start();
     super.doStart();
}
```

You would have to wire up this (and your bean) manually. Probably the easiest thing to do is have your `InputSource` implement `MessageSource`...

```
@Component
public class InputSource implements MessageSource<String>, Lifecycle {

    private boolean running;

    @Override
    public void start() {
        System.out.println("start");
        running = true;
    }

    @Override
    public void stop() {
        running = false;
    }

    @Override
    public Message<String> receive() {
        return new GenericMessage<String>("foo");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isRunning() {
        return running;
    }

}
```

And wire it into your `MySPCA`, together with polling info.

I created an [Improvement JIRA Issue](https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT-3571) to support this use case.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm looking to get the adapter's `start()` to call the `InputSource.start()` when invoked via jmx for example.

Comment: Like I said - it's a different bean - it's not the adapter; it's a bean called `inputSource`.

Comment: But is what I'm looking to do even doable?

Comment: Oh and thats spring integration 4.0.4.RELEASE

Comment: Thanks for the time! Ill definitely do that